# How to find what download destination an application uses?

Tags: windows-7, windows, download, path

There are many applications able to update themselves standalone... but how could I find out what Windows path that application uses to download all necessary files. (probably temp).

I could searched all most recent updated directories.. but is there anything better that that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can watch file access with [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645).